# which api to use for an app providing list of nearby hospitals with available treatment types?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am building an android app which can **suggest a list of hospitals/clinics/doctors who specialize in specific division of medicine**.

For e.g If a person searches for orthopedics, the app should list all nearby hospitals which specialize in orthopedics.

I am new to android development and have never used any api like the Google Map API or the Google Places API. I read that other vendors like yelp etc. don't have enough information about such services.

Can someone help me decide which API I should be using here?

Also, when do we use google map api vs a google places api ?
Links to tutorials explaining how to use these apis would also be very helpful.

Comment: I happened to see this. Try reading this https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-each-Places-API

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using either the Google Places API like you have mentioned or the yelp API:

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start

https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api

I, have personally used the yelp API for a personal project of mine and it pretty much does what I want it to. Please look at the documentation in both the links above and see what fits your application the best (both should work based on the description you provided). Hope this helps!

Comment: The main entry points for the Google Places API for Android are the PlacePicker UI widget, the GeoDataApi, and the PlaceDetectionApi. Does it mean I cannot use any of the APIs listed at https://github.com/windy1/google-places-api-java ? I am not able to find any example of how to use the google places API for android. Also, I specifically want to use List<Place> places = client.getPlacesByQuery("Empire State Building", GooglePlaces.MAXIMUM_RESULTS, Param.name("language").value("en"), Param.name("opennow").value(true));